# SharePoint embed of Silverlight app breaking ControlTemplates

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, controltemplate

Strange problem here, I have a page with 4 ControlTemplates declared in the page resources. In the code for the page, I declare a reference to each of these ControlTemplates so that I can use them in binding. This works fine Out-Of-Browser, and In-Browser, except when it is running in the Silverlight Web Part in SharePoint. In SharePoint, the buttons that I want templated are shown as just normal buttons with the class as the text instead of the special layout and content I define in the template. Any idea why it would work everywhere but in SharePoint?

Comment: I've used the Application_UnhandledException method in App.xaml.cs to catch an error that says object reference not set to an instance of an object. Still not sure why this would only be an issue in SharePoint's Silverlight Web Part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure what caused the null reference only while being ran in SharePoint, I refactored my code to make the ItemsControl.ItemsSource reference a property instead of a single assignment of a List<> to it. Now it is working just like it should.

Helpful in figuring this out was the ability to attach Visual Studio to the Internet Explorer (didn't work so well for Chrome) process that was running the Silverlight Web Part. This is found in Visual Studio by going to the Tools menu > Attach to Process. Which IE process it is will be obvious as it will have Silverlight in the Type column.